# Taxonomy archive + query attachments = duplicate results [wordpress]

Tags: php, wordpress, attachment, taxonomy

I'm trying to get the attachments of a specific term (in its archive page).
But the results are showing the resulting images 5 times instead of one.

I have multiple loops in this page - one to show related posts, another to show related products (custom post), and this one to show related images. Custom posts and posts are working nicely, but I can't show the attachments in the right way. :S

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id; 

    $args = array(
    'post_status' => 'inherit',
    'numberposts' => 0,
    'post__not_in' => array_merge($do_not_duplicate,get_option( 'sticky_posts' )),
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
    );

    $args['tax_query'] = array(
    array(
        'taxonomy' => 't-arte',
        'terms' => $term_id,
        'field' => 'id',
    ),
    ); ?>

    <?php $t = $data['t-arte'];
$array = explode(" ", $t);
$array = array_unique($array);?>

<?php $media_query = array_unique($array); ?>

    <?php $media_query = get_posts($args);
    if( !empty( $media_query ) ) :
    foreach ($media_query as $media_query) :
global $post; $post = $media_query;
    setup_postdata($media_query);
    ?>

<div id="archivespage-media-item">   

    <?php $attachments = get_posts( $args );
                     if ( $attachments ) {
                        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
                           echo '<div id="imagem">';
                           the_attachment_link( $attachment->ID, true );
                           echo '</div>';
                           }
                     }?>

</div>

<?php endforeach;else :?>       

 <p>Ainda não temos nenhuma imagem relacionada :(</p>  

 </div>

 <?php endif; ?>
        <?php wp_reset_query();?>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I've done these and its working!

The result will show all attachments in a specific term inside term's archive page.

```
<?php $queried_object = get_queried_object();
$term_id = $queried_object->term_id; 

global $wp_query;

$original_query['tax_query'] = array(
array(
'taxonomy' => 't-arte',
'terms' => $term_id,
'field' => 'id',
 ),);

$original_query = (array) $wp_query;

$attach_query = array(
'post_type'=> array( 'attachment' ),
'post_status' => array( null ));
$args = array_merge($original_query['query_vars'], $attach_query);

$media_query = new WP_Query( $args )?>

<?php  if($media_query->have_posts()) :
while ($media_query->have_posts() ) : $media_query->the_post();
if( $post->ID == $do_not_duplicate ) continue; ?>

<div id="archivespage-media-item">   

<div id="imagem">
<?php echo wp_get_attachment_link($attachment->ID, 'bigger-thumb');?>
 </div>

</div>

<?php endwhile; else: ?>    

//do stuff       

</div>
```

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/29635/how-to-create-an-attachments-archive-with-working-pagination